# HTML have text be right to a figure with image slider

Tags: html, css

So currently I have an image slider at the left side, but the figure in that slide is set to width: 500%, I want to have text to the right of this figure, but when I try to put text there, it drops down below the image. I need text to the right of the figure image slider and the image on the left side.

```css
#imgslide {
  width: 550px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#imgslide figure img {
  opacity: .7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#imgslide figure img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  position: relative;
  width: 23%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
}
#imgslide figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 15s slidy infinite;
}
/* Keyframes */

@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="imgslide">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=52&txt=550%C3%97300&w=550&h=300" alt="">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=52&txt=550%C3%97300&w=550&h=300" alt="">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=52&txt=550%C3%97300&w=550&h=300" alt="">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the property to .image-slider.

```
float: left;
```

Then create a new div, for example:

```
<div id="text-container">
  <p>
    Text example
  </p>
</div>
```

And put the property to .text-container

```
float:right;
```